# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed') React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cryptojs, web3js

am developing a mobile app using React native, which involves an interaction with `web3.js`
and Problem is RN does not support core Node.js modules, so I had to install

`npm i --save react-native-crypto`

`npm i --save react-native-randombytes`

`react-native link react-native-randombytes`

`npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest`

`./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install`

and now I face this error whenever I try to use `crypto or web3.js`
[image]

Any clue what's the issue or maybe how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like installation problem of react-native-randombytes library.

Did not you think about using the different, more popular library that offers same API?

npm says that react-native-randombytes has 19,294 weekly downloads.
Another library called react-native-get-random-values (with cca 481,572 weekly downloads) is almost guaranteed to work (as it is recommended to use in combination with packages like - [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#readme) ). The npm link for this library is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values).

By taking look at the source code of both libraries that were mentioned above, both use the same Android API, backed by SecureRandom, so I would expect that there are similarities on iOS too.

react-native-get-random-values (link [here](https://github.com/LinusU/react-native-get-random-values/blob/master/android/src/main/java/org/linusu/RNGetRandomValuesModule.java) ):

```
@ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
  public String getRandomBase64(int byteLength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] data = new byte[byteLength];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    random.nextBytes(data);

    return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  }
```

react-native-randombytes library - link [here](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/bitgo/randombytes/RandomBytesModule.java):

```
@ReactMethod
  public void randomBytes(int size, Callback success) {
    success.invoke(null, getRandomBytes(size));
  }

private String getRandomBytes(int size) {
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] output = new byte[size];
    sr.nextBytes(output);
    return Base64.encodeToString(output, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  }
```

Comment: I just tried.  `react-native-get-random-values` . I installed it and added the.  `import 'react-native-get-random-values'.`  in the `index.js` but I face almost the same issue 

` ERROR TypeError: _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "./getRandomBase64") is not a function. (In '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "./getRandomBase64")(array.byteLength)', '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "./getRandomBase64")' is undefined) `

Comment: 1. kill / close metro bundler and debugger
2. npm install --save react-native-get-random-values
3. cd ios && pod install, then cd ..
4. put 'import 'react-native-get-random-values'  at the first line of index.js
5.  - getRandomValues modifies 'global' object (and its crypto property) - you can inspect this object in devtools with console.log
10. then you can access library api like e.g:

//  !!API does not support 'Array' type, so see supported Array types in lib docs
const array = new Uint8Array(10); 
global.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
console.log(array) 

11. run app

Comment: Gist => https://gist.github.com/majirosstefan/3f9bbf37837ea1b699e47a4674c9b3e0

Comment: But I need exactly `react-native-randombytes` because `react-native-crypto` uses it as a dependency. What can I do?

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck fixing the error ?

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on this answer? I have swapped out `react-native-randombytes` for `react-native-get-random-values` and i still get exactly the same error `(RNRandomBytes.see null)`. I'm not sure what to even try next :/

Comment: I simply proposed to swap the library with the alternative that uses compatible API - but as it's different library it may expose different methods to RN (e.g. w/ different name and/or parameters).

Also, React Native RandomBytes seems to be deprecated now:

https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes#readme

Use react-native-get-random-values instead: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values

If you need to use lib that has dependency to unmaintained lib, you can fork it or patch it.

Comment: Ok. It seems though that 'react-native-crypto' still wants to use 'react-native-randombytes'..... Does this mean i have to fork/change the react-native-crypto node module to use get-random-values instead?

Comment: Inside the node_module 'react-native-crypro', i have now changed the line to be: `import { randomBytes } from 'react-native-get-random-values'`, but now i am back to the `undefined not an object evaluating process.version.split`. I keep going in circles with this, its ever so confusing. How to make process available in react native?

Answer (score 0):

## Use package

Install [@kitzen/react-native-bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kitzen/react-native-bip39) and follow setup instructions

## Setup manually

1. If you use expo, get rid of it
2. Halt the Metro server.
3. I don't know why, but **gradle won't install a native module, unless it's explicitly defined in package.json**, so please add this to the dependencies section:

```json
    "react-native-crypto": "*",
    "react-native-randombytes": "*",
```

4. Use android-native setup. Switch to `android` directory in the project root and run:

```
./gradlew build
```

Yep you'll need to install AndroidStudio and Android SDK if you haven't done it yet.

Gradle is an module builder, it should list all your native modules, including `react-native-randombytes`, like this:

```
> Task :react-native-randombytes:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-randombytes:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-randombytes:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-randombytes:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
```

4. Start the Metro server and press `a` to deploy Android APK. If you won't redeploy the app, javascript files will be  uploaded, but not native modules

Comment: I had exactly the same issues in 2017... Time goes by, and react native bridge is as buggy as it was 6 years ago