# React native - undefined is not an object (evaluating '_bip.default.generateMnemonic')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, passphrase

I'm building a mobile application and I need to generate a passphrase using `bip39`.
At first, when I installed the package from npm I got missing dependencies error concerning `assert`, `events`, `stream` and `buffer`. I installed the mentioned packages and I got the following error when I try to use `bip39` library in my code :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_bip.default.generateMnemonic')
> at components/newAccount.jsx:8:23 in handleSubmit
> at components/newAccount.jsx:6:23 in handleSubmit
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:697:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:634:6 in _receiveSignal
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:528:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease

Here is the code implementation :

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
try {
  let seed = await bip39.generateMnemonic(256) // default to 128
  console.log(seed)
  return seed
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)

}
navigation.navigate("Passphrase")
}
```

I also tried to use `react-native-bip39` but no luck, I received a similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142137/react-native-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rnrandombytes-seed)

P.S : The application was created with Expo cli.

Comment: Unfortunately not